# Applying CSS to template field

Tags: jquery, .net, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery template to display records. Code is

```
<script id="SalesTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> 
<form id="enterForm" action ="">
        <tbody>
            {{#each items}}
             <tr class="row{{* { res += ($Number % 2);  } }}">
                 <!--td>{{=rId}}</td-->
                 <td>{{=company}}</td>
                 <td>{{=colorLabel}}</td>
                 <td>{{=dueDate}}</td>
             </tr>
            {{/each}}    
        </tbody>           
    </table>         
</form>
```

What I want to do is if colorLabel value is red i want value written in red fond and if it is green to be written in green font. Any ideas how can I achieve that? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the color hex or rgb value as well? 
Then you could do:

```
<td style="color:{{=colorValue}}">{{=colorLabel}}</td>
```

If not, you could try if your colorLabels match the [css color names](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/color/keywords) and do this:

```
<td style="color:{{=colorLabel}}">{{=colorLabel}}</td>
```

Alternatively, you could set the colorLabel as class and set the color in css:

```
<td class="{{=colorLabel}}">{{=colorLabel}}</td>
```

Css

```
td.red{
    color:#f00;
}
td.blue{
    color:#00f;
}
...
```

Comment: In <td class="{{=colorLabel}}">{{=colorLabel}}</td>

Answer (score 0):

This will go through all cells, and check the text.
If the text value is 'red', it will change the font color to red.
If the text value is 'green', it will change the font color to green.

```
$('table td').each( function(){
    if ( $(this).html() == 'red' ) {
       $(this).css("color", "red");
    } else if ( $(this).html() == 'green' ){
       $(this).css("color", "green");
    }
});
```